# WordPress load script only on homepage, else add class

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Not really sure how to achieve what I am trying to do here, hopefully you guys can help.
I have a script within my function.js file which makes my fixed header fade into view when the page is scrolled down to a certain point.

I want this script to work as it is on the home page, but I'd like to have the header permanently visible on all interior pages.

i'm sure this will require breaking this script out into it's own file and changing it around a bit, but I'm open to suggestion.

My initial thoughts are to have the script run as intended on the homepage, but create some sort of else/if php statement that says:

"if this is the home page, do nothing, else, add a class of opaque to the element #navbar"

HTML:

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar bg transition">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-small.png" alt="Jot logo" class="navlogo">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu" id="mobilemenu">
                  <span class="menu-global menu-top"></span>
                  <span class="menu-global menu-middle"></span>
                  <span class="menu-global menu-bottom"></span>
                </div>
            <div id="menuexpand">
                <div>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- #navbar -->
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
  background: #525454;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.transition {    
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar {
  background: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  padding-top: 15px;
  top: 0;
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // 100 = The point you would like to fade the nav in.

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){

      $('.bg').addClass('show');

    } else {

      $('.bg').removeClass('show');

    };    
  });

  $('.scroll').on('click', function(e){   
      e.preventDefault()

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : $(this.hash).offset().top
      }, 1500);
  });
```

Any ideas here? Like I said, I am open to suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's my solution:

I created a JS script:

```
(function ($) {
  $('#navbar').addClass('show');
}(jQuery));
```

Then I tweaked the if/else posted earlier:

`<?php
        if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script('header-fade', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/header-fade.js');
    } else { 
            wp_enqueue_script('opaque', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/opaque.js');
        }; 
?>`

So, if it's the front page (home), the fade on scroll script fires.
If it's any other page, the opaque script fires instead which makes the navbar visible on page load.

Done and done.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the body in your home page. And layout the .bg with fixed position as you want for that other pages:

```
<body class="home">

:not(.home) .bg{position:fixed;}
```

Comment: not quite sure what this would achieve. I tried it, but no luck. This is WP, so the home class on the body gets applied to every page in the site. I also tried this method with opacity:1 instead of position:fixed, but that nullified my scroll fade effect on the homepage.

Comment: Can't you assign different classes for different pages?

Comment: well, the pages are generated via the WP loop, so the opening body tag is in the header.php file which is added to every page on the site.

Comment: Take a look at adeneo answer which might help you. I don't know wordpress, so I can't say to do , how..?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script($scriptUrl);
} else { 
    add_filter("body_class" , function($classes){
        $classes[] = "added-class";
        return $classes;
    }); 
}
```

If it's home, enqueue some script (should be done before `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. Else it will add some classes to body. Remember tho that you need to make proper body tag

```
<body <php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Can I do  //     add_filter(#navbar ....    // and have it add a class to the navbar ID element?

Comment: so, this loads my script properly, but on interior pages it does not add the 'show' class to my #navbar element

Comment: `<?php
   if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { 
      wp_enqueue_script('header-fade', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/header-fade.js');
  } else { 
      add_filter('#navbar' , function($classes){
          $classes[] = '.show';
          return $classes;
      }); 
  } 
 ?>`