# How can I make this code only work on the main page of a WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How can I make this code only work on the main page of a WordPress site?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scrolled;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (scrolled > 400) {
      $(".mega-menu-link").css({
        "color": "rgba(102,102,102,0.85)"
      })
    }

    if (400 > scrolled) {
      $(".mega-menu-link").css({
        "color": "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Only include it on the main page then?

Comment: provide more details, such as where is js code located, what you tried and etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Specific Js on Specific page Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019661/run-specific-js-on-specific-page-wordpress) or [WordPress load script only on homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325811/wordpress-load-script-only-on-homepage-else-add-class).

Comment: Also see [Most efficient way to add javascript file to specific post and/or pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67802/most-efficient-way-to-add-javascript-file-to-specific-post-and-or-pages) and [Wordpress Enqueue for homepage only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/wordpress-enqueue-for-homepage-only-functions-php-wp-framework).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to include your script only on the main page is to put your code into the file and use `if` condition in the header or footer. Also you can include your code only into the main page as mented above.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){?>
    <script src="your_script.js"></script>  
<?php } ?>
```